# How to extract words from full text output with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some text output like bellow, then I need to separate the words before and after \n.

Output:
`'Word1\nWord2\n01:17\n2\n0'`

What I need:

- `let Word1 = "Word"1` separated
- `let Word2 = "Word2"` separated
- `let Time = "01:17"` (Time in minutes separated (I will need to do some if condition checking if is greater than 20:00 and less than 40:00 later so I think the variable should be in time minutes format)).
- `let Number1 = 2`
- `let Number2 = 0`

Comment: What have you tried? Did you find the split command?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP I haven't idea to start. I'll try to find about split. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic of it:

```
var message = "Word1\nWord2\n01:17\n2\n0";
var camp = message.split("\n"); //splits the string 

let word1 = camp[0];
let word2 = camp[1];
let time = camp[2];
let number1 = camp[3];
let number2 = camp[4];

console.log(word1 + " " + word2 + " " + time + " " + number1 + " " + number2); //Will return "Word1 Word2 01:17 2 0"
```

Now, you just need to split time again to seperate the hours from the minutes.

---

Keep The Good Work